# How do I tag when rolling joins take effect in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Hi I'm struggling to distinguish when a particular event has occurred in my data twice. Let's say for example's sake that I've got 3 types of events - a,b,c - and each of them is valid for 3 periods.

I want to create a period series of active events where any change in event replaces the previous event, but if the current event repeats, it restarts. Here's some code to illustrate:

```r
a1 <- data.table(
  c(1, 4, 7, 8),
  c("a", "a", "c", "d")
)

a2 <- data.table(
  c(1, 7, 8),
  c("a", "c", "d")
)

b <- data.table(
  seq(1, 8)
)

setkey(a1, V1)
setkey(a2, V1)
setkey(b, V1)

a1[b, roll = 2]

a2[b, roll = 2]
```

As you can see with a1, I get a mush of event type a's and i don't get much information back on where event a actually repeated. Ideally I'd like my join to qualify the events as such:

```
data.table(
  c(1:8),
  c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "c", "d"),
  event = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
)
```

Any ideas? Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you need this answer for both joins?

Comment: just for a1, a2 is more to illustrate the issue further

Comment: You could join back to `a1`: `a1[b, roll = 2][a1, on = 'V1', event := +!is.na(i.V1)]`

Comment: IceCreamToucan that's perfect! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if your keys (`V1` in your example) matched during the join:

```
a1[b, .(V2 = x.V2, event = isTRUE(x.V1 == i.V1)), roll = 2, by = .EACHI]
   V1 V2 event
1:  1  a  TRUE
2:  2  a FALSE
3:  3  a FALSE
4:  4  a  TRUE
5:  5  a FALSE
6:  6  a FALSE
7:  7  c  TRUE
8:  8  d  TRUE

a2[b, .(V2 = x.V2, event = isTRUE(x.V1 == i.V1)), roll = 2, by = .EACHI]
   V1   V2 event
1:  1    a  TRUE
2:  2    a FALSE
3:  3    a FALSE
4:  4 <NA> FALSE
5:  5 <NA> FALSE
6:  6 <NA> FALSE
7:  7    c  TRUE
8:  8    d  TRUE
```

---

Taking into account the comments in this answer:

```
set.seed(5438L)
n <- 1e5
a <- data.table(
        sample(2 * n, n, replace = FALSE),
        sample(c("a", "b", "c"), n, replace = TRUE),
        key = "V1"
)

b <- data.table(1:(2 * n), key = "V1")

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
        during = a[b, c(.SD, event = isTRUE(x.V1 == i.V1)), roll = 2, by = .EACHI],
        after = a[b, roll = 2][a, event := !is.na(i.V1), on = "V1"],
        times = 30L
)
Unit: milliseconds
   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
 during 767.49338 771.49878 795.02283 776.20243 787.96382 964.11575    30   b
  after  26.14068  26.46543  28.58425  27.51831  29.73552  37.36052    30  a
```

So IceCreamToucan's answer is probably better in this case.

Comment: like this solution as it's performed in-join - thanks! Any thoughts on the performance of doing this in-join versus using rleid to assign the events on the resulting DT as suggested in the some of the other answers?

Comment: To avoid typing names in a case with more columns you could do `c(.SD, event = isTRUE(x.V1 == i.V1))` in place of `.(V2 = x.V2, event = isTRUE(x.V1 == i.V1))`

Comment: @codesaurus I'm also not sure if the `rleid` versions generalize, but if they do, they might be faster. I'm not sure, it would be interesting to test. AFAIK, `data.table` evaluates `j` for each match in the join to save memory, but that might sacrifice speed (probably due to overhead in evaluating R code each time). Since your problem mostly seems to have single matches per key, modifying post-join might be better. If so, @IcecreamToucan's answer in the OP's comments might be faster.

Comment: I should have mentioned that although the `c(.SD,` option is easier to type/read (according to my subjective preferences), it is also slower than your original answer

Comment: @IceCreamToucan your comment has `+!is.na(i.V1)`, is that first `+` there on purpose?

Comment: Yeah it's a (sloppy) way of converting to numeric. Without it you get `TRUE`s instead of `1`s

Comment: i tried the faster version, but it's hitting a "join results in more than 2^31 rows (internal vecseq reached physical limit)" error on a large dataset. Adding a by = .EACHI solves it, but then seems to be doing nonsense.. any suggestions?

Comment: @codesaurus What exactly do you mean by nonsense? In the case here, there were only single matches per row, so it shouldn't be possible for a join to have more rows than the input. Does your larger dataset have repeated keys?

Answer (score 4):

Repeat the vector 1,0,0 to a length of .N for each group using `rleid` to form the groups.

```
k <- 3 # restart after this number of events that are the same
one.zeros <- rep(1:0, c(1, k-1))  # length k vector.  For k=3, c(1,0,0)
DT[, V3 := rep(one.zeros, length = .N), by = rleid(V2)]
```

giving:

```
> DT
   V1 V2 V3
1:  1  a  1
2:  2  a  0
3:  3  a  0
4:  4  a  1
5:  5  a  0
6:  6  a  0
7:  7  c  1
8:  8  c  0
9:  9  d  1
```

### Note

The input `DT` is:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(1:9, c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "c", "c", "d"))
```

Comment: this solution seems interesting, but I'm not quite sure how to generalise. When I apply it to a time series where my events last >2 periods it seems to still tag an event occurring every 3rd period (even though that's not true)

Comment: yes that's right, but this is a microcosm of my problem so I just need to understand what the lever is to change that 3 period to 30 for example. Does the vector change? Or is it another input in the code.

Comment: It assigns 1 to the first element of the group and then assigns 0 to the second and third and then starts over again with 1 at the fourth element and so on.   I have modified the example in the Note in my answer so you can see it works correctly for groups of length 2.

Comment: @codesaurus To extend `c(1, 0, 0)` to a vector of length 30 with a 1 in the first position, there's `replace(integer(30), 1L, 1L)`

Comment: thanks approach seems very cool, I'll probably revisit it if I have performance issues, going with the in-join version for now

Comment: Have generalized using `k`.

Answer (score 3):

Another variant of @GaborGrothendieck's answer:

```
DT[, v := 0L]
DT[(rowid(rleid(V2)) - 1L) %% 3 == 0, v := 1L][]

   V1 V2 v
1:  1  a 1
2:  2  a 0
3:  3  a 0
4:  4  a 1
5:  5  a 0
6:  6  a 0
7:  7  c 1
8:  8  c 0
9:  9  d 1
```

This just does arithmetic on the `rowid` (1,2,3...) within each `rleid` group.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully have understood OP's intentions behind the question but I believe this can be solved alternatively *without* join.

If I understand correctly, the goal is to expand a list of events

> ```
>    V1 V2
> 1:  1  a
> 2:  4  a
> 3:  7  c
> 4:  8  d
> ```

into a *period series of active events*

> ```
>    V1 V2 event
> 1:  1  a     1
> 2:  2  a     0
> 3:  3  a     0
> 4:  4  a     1
> 5:  5  a     0
> 6:  6  a     0
> 7:  7  c     1
> 8:  8  d     1
> ```

In the input data.table, `V1` denotes the time index when an event of type `V2` took place. So, we can repeat each value of `V2` until the next event. The `event` column is created by comparing the positions given in `a1$V1` with the time index sequence:

```
a1[, .(1:max(V1), rep(V2, c(diff(V1), 1)), event = +(1:max(V1) %in% V1))]
```

> ```
>    V1 V2 event
> 1:  1  a     1
> 2:  2  a     0
> 3:  3  a     0
> 4:  4  a     1
> 5:  5  a     0
> 6:  6  a     0
> 7:  7  c     1
> 8:  8  d     1
> ```

(Note that `1:max(V1) %in% V1` is of type logical, `+(1:max(V1) %in% V1)` coerces this to integer.)

---

Also, there are two variants which return the same result but may differ in performance (not benchmarked):

```
a1[, .(1:max(V1), rep(V2, c(diff(V1), 1)), event = replace(rep(0L, max(V1)), V1, 1L))]
```

uses `replace()` to create the `event` column.

```
a1[, .(1:max(V1), rep(V2, c(diff(V1), 1)), event = 0L)][a1$V1, event := 1L][]
```

initialises the `event` column but updates it selectively in a subsequent step.